# MariaDB: How can I select a temporary table if there is a persistent table with the same name?

Tags: mariadb, temp-tables

I created a persistent table `temp` and a temporary table `temp`, that is, both have the same name. How can I use select/update/insert specifically to the persistent or the temporary table? How can I differ between them?

MariaDB [Tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mariadb/mariadb_temporary_tables.htm) says:

> Note − Temporary tables are permitted to have the same name as an existing non-temporary table because MariaDB views it as a difference reference.

So, I suppose it should be possible to refer to one of these tables. This question is related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59372342/how-mariadb-administrates-temporary-tables) I posed in SO, but goes one step back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case a temporary table has the same name as an existing non temporary table the temporary table will shadow the name of a non temporary table.

That means in a SQL statement you will not be able to reference the non temporary table.

A work around would be, to create a view on a non temporary table before creating the temporary table, since the view internally keeps the reference to the non temporary table:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (a VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES ("foo");
CREATE VIEW v_t1 AS SELECT a FROM t1;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t1 (b VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES ("bar");
SELECT * FROM v_t1;
SELECT * FROM t1;
```

Comment: That's it. As long a temporary table exists, all `selects`, `updates` and `inserts` and even `drop table` will be performed on the temporary table.